# SVN - reintegrate a branch without updating it

Tags: svn, merge

I use branches to be able to maintain previous release versions of my project. Whenever I release a version I create a branch named for the released version (for example, v1.2) and my current development is continued in the trunk.

After fixing some bugs in the branch, I want to reintegrate them into the trunk. However, in order to do that properly I have to update the branch first. Obviously I don't want to do this as I don't want to include any new development into the previous product version.

I understand why this is problematic for SVN to perform such a merge but nevertheless, is 
there any way to accomplish that? Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: The branch should be "up to date" when you fix your bugs in it. You should just need to merge the branch into the trunk.

Comment: But it can't be "up to date" in my model, as the trunk now contains new features that I don't want to be merged into the previous version.

Comment: If trunk is development, and you fix bugs in production, then you need to merge production -> development, right? So you would merge the branch into the trunk, and you would not need to update the branch as you are updating the trunk.

Comment: And you don't necessarily want a *reintegrate*. What it looks like you want is to merge the changes you did in the branch.

Comment: So I should "merge revisions" instead of "Reintegrate" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're doing something wrong. You should just merge the changes done in the maintenance branch to the trunk.

You're confusing maintenance branches with feature branches, which must stay up-to-date with the trunk before reintegrating them in the trunk.

Comment: So I should "merge revisions" instead of "Reintegrate" ?

Comment: Yes. If you fix a bug in the branch (which leads to revision 1000 to be created), and if you want this bug fix to be ported to the trunk, you just need to merge the revision 1000 from branch to trunk (i.e. the diff between rev 999 and rev 1000 in the branch must be merged into trunk).